# How to Print HTML From response + data in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

[image]I need an assistant to get the HTML data in google sheet. I have created an HTML web app from here users will submit the Attendance responses.

In HTML web app I have generated Login information (IP and OS) + Location + User Email address + User will visit this page and they will submit the response (Attendance)

I want to print all below information in Google Sheet 
Email address, IP, OS, Location, TimeStamp, Emp code, Org and Shift Timing

Thanks in advance

```js
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index")
.evaluate()
.setTitle("User Agent - Google Apps Script");
}

function getCurrentUserEmail()
{
  var email={'email':Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()};//returned as an object
  return email;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */ 
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    
    /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
    .row.content {height: 450px}
    
    /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
    .sidenav {
      padding-top: 20px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    footer {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px;
    }
    
    /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .sidenav {
        height: auto;
        padding: 15px;
      }
      .row.content {height:auto;} 
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <img src="" alt="LOGO" style="width:100px;height:50px;">
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"> Attendance Application</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav> 
<div class="container-fluid text-center">    
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
   <a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
        </a> 
      <p><script type="text/javascript">
tday=new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
tmonth=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");

function GetClock(){
var d=new Date();
var nday=d.getDay(),nmonth=d.getMonth(),ndate=d.getDate(),nyear=d.getFullYear();
var nhour=d.getHours(),nmin=d.getMinutes(),nsec=d.getSeconds(),ap;

if(nhour==0){ap=" AM";nhour=12;}
else if(nhour<12){ap=" AM";}
else if(nhour==12){ap=" PM";}
else if(nhour>12){ap=" PM";nhour-=12;}

if(nmin<=9) nmin="0"+nmin;
if(nsec<=9) nsec="0"+nsec;

document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML=""+tday[nday]+", "+tmonth[nmonth]+" "+ndate+", "+nyear+" "+nhour+":"+nmin+":"+nsec+ap+"";
}

window.onload=function(){
GetClock();
setInterval(GetClock,1000);
}
</script>
<div id="clockbox"></div>
</p>
<p>
</p>
<br>
</br>
<br>
</br>
<p>
 <a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></span>
        </a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.brainyquote.com/link/quotebr.js"></script>
</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-left"> 
    <h1></h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date();
    var time = d.getHours();
    
    if (time >= 0 && time < 12) 
      {
      document.write("<b>Good Morning!</b>");
      }
    if (time >= 12 && time < 17) 
      {
      document.write("<b>Good Afternoon!</b>");
      }
    if (time >= 17 && time < 24) 
      {
      document.write("<b>Good Evening!</b>");
      }
    </script>
    <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {

    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(dispEmail)
      .getCurrentUserEmail();
     });//runs after dom is loaded
     function dispEmail(data)
     {
       $('#email').text(data.email);//put's email into h1 tag
     }
     console.log('My Code');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h5 id="email"></h5>
      <hr>
      <div class="alert alert-info">
    <strong>Info!</strong> You need to Check-In, last time you have done Check-Out..!
  </div>
      </style>
<body>
<div>
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Emp Code:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="Emp Code" class="form-control" id="Emp Code" placeholder="Emp Code you will get in ID Card eg:Tech-RV 341, Just Enter Number 341">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Shift Timing">Shift Timing :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <select class="form-control" id="control-label col-sm-2">
        <option>M - Morning =7:00 AM to 3:30 PM</option>
        <option>M - Morning =8:00 AM to 4:00 PM</option>
        <option>M - Morning =8:00 AM to 4:30 PM</option>
        <option>M - Morning =8:00 AM to 5:00 PM</option>
        <option>M I- Morning= 8:30 AM to 5:30 PM</option>
        <option>M 2- Morning =8:30 AM to 5:00 PM</option>
        <option>G- General =9:00 AM to 5:30 PM</option>
        <option>G1- General =9:00 AM to 6:00 PM</option>
        <option>G2- General =9:30 AM to 6:30 PM</option>
        <option>G3- General =9:30 AM to 6:00 PM</option>
        <option>G4- Late General =10:00 AM to 7:00 PM</option>
        <option>G4- Late General =10:00 AM to 6:30 PM</option>
        <option>G5- General =11:00 AM to 7:00:00 PM</option>
        <option>G6 - Late General =11:00 AM to 8:00 PM</option>
        <option>A-=12:00 PM to  9:00 PM</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Org Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <select class="form-control" id="control-label col-sm-2">
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">    Check-In    </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">    Check-Out    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
<div>
 
</div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      <div class="well">
        <p>Login Information</p>
         <div id="browser"></div>
    <div id="os"></div>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js/master/dist/ua-parser.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var parser = new UAParser();
      parser.setUA("<?= HtmlService.getUserAgent(); ?>");
      var result = parser.getResult();
      document.getElementById("browser").textContent = result.browser.name + " v" + result.browser.major;
      document.getElementById("os").textContent = result.os.name + " v" + result.os.version;
    </script>
     <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $("#ip").html(userip);
        google.script.run.getvalue(userip);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="ip"></p>
  </body>
   <a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);

        function success(position) {
            console.log(position.coords.latitude)
            console.log(position.coords.longitude)

            var GEOCODING = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + position.coords.latitude + '%2C' + position.coords.longitude + '&language=en';

            $.getJSON(GEOCODING).done(function(location) {
                console.log(location)
            })

        }

        function error(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>

<body>


    <p>City: <span id="state"></span></p>

    <p>Address: <span id="address"></span></p>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);

        function success(position) {

            var GEOCODING = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + position.coords.latitude + '%2C' + position.coords.longitude + '&language=en';

            $.getJSON(GEOCODING).done(function(location) {
               // $('#country').html(location.results[0].address_components[5].long_name);
                $('#state').html(location.results[0].address_components[4].long_name);
               // $('#city').html(location.results[0].address_components[2].long_name);
                $('#address').html(location.results[0].formatted_address);
               // $('#latitude').html(position.coords.latitude);
               // $('#longitude').html(position.coords.longitude);
            })

        }

        function error(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    </script>
  <a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p>Test</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Provide a snap of the final output (print file)

Comment: or do you want to store data from html form to Google Sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By what I understood from your question is that you are trying to save html form data into Google spreadsheet. If that is the case, I have modified your code.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */

        .navbar {
            margin-bottom: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
        }
        /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */

        .row.content {
            height: 450px
        }
        /* Set gray background color and 100% height */

        .sidenav {
            padding-top: 20px;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            height: 100%;
        }
        /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */

        footer {
            background-color: #555;
            color: white;
            padding: 15px;
        }
        /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */

        @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
            .sidenav {
                height: auto;
                padding: 15px;
            }
            .row.content {
                height: auto;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header"> <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button> <img src="" alt="LOGO" style="width:100px;height:50px;"> </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#"> Attendance Application</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div class="row content">
            <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav"> <a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
        </a>
                <p>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        tday = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
                        tmonth = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

                        function GetClock() {
                            var d = new Date();
                            var nday = d.getDay(),
                                nmonth = d.getMonth(),
                                ndate = d.getDate(),
                                nyear = d.getFullYear();
                            var nhour = d.getHours(),
                                nmin = d.getMinutes(),
                                nsec = d.getSeconds(),
                                ap;
                            if (nhour == 0) {
                                ap = " AM";
                                nhour = 12;
                            } else if (nhour < 12) {
                                ap = " AM";
                            } else if (nhour == 12) {
                                ap = " PM";
                            } else if (nhour > 12) {
                                ap = " PM";
                                nhour -= 12;
                            }
                            if (nmin <= 9) nmin = "0" + nmin;
                            if (nsec <= 9) nsec = "0" + nsec;
                            document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML = "" + tday[nday] + ", " + tmonth[nmonth] + " " + ndate + ", " + nyear + " " + nhour + ":" + nmin + ":" + nsec + ap + "";
                        }
                        window.onload = function() {
                            GetClock();
                            setInterval(GetClock, 1000);
                        }
                    </script>
                    <div id="clockbox"></div>
                </p>
                <p> </p> <br> </br> <br> </br>
                <p> <a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></span>
        </a>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.brainyquote.com/link/quotebr.js"></script>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 text-left">
                <h1></h1>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var d = new Date();
                    var time = d.getHours();
                    if (time >= 0 && time < 12) {
                        document.write("<b>Good Morning!</b>");
                    }
                    if (time >= 12 && time < 17) {
                        document.write("<b>Good Afternoon!</b>");
                    }
                    if (time >= 17 && time < 24) {
                        document.write("<b>Good Evening!</b>");
                    }
                </script>

                <head>
                    <base target="_top">
                    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script>
                        $(function() {
                            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(dispEmail).getCurrentUserEmail();
                        }); //runs after dom is loaded
                        function dispEmail(data) {
                            $('#email').text(data.email); //put's email into h1 tag
                        }
                        console.log('My Code');
                    </script>
                </head>

                <body>
                    <h5 id="email"></h5>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="alert alert-info"> <strong>Info!</strong> You need to Check-In, last time you have done Check-Out..! </div>
                    </style>

                    <body>
                        <div>
                            <form class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Emp Code:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10"> <input type="Emp Code" class="form-control" id="EmpCode" placeholder="Emp Code you will get in ID Card eg:Tech-RV 341, Just Enter Number 341"> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Shift Timing">Shift Timing :</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10"> <select class="form-control" id="shiftTiming">
                                      <option>M - Morning =7:00 AM to 3:30 PM</option>
                                      <option>M - Morning =8:00 AM to 4:00 PM</option>
                                      <option>M - Morning =8:00 AM to 4:30 PM</option>
                                      <option>M - Morning =8:00 AM to 5:00 PM</option>
                                      <option>M I- Morning= 8:30 AM to 5:30 PM</option>
                                      <option>M 2- Morning =8:30 AM to 5:00 PM</option>
                                      <option>G- General =9:00 AM to 5:30 PM</option>
                                      <option>G1- General =9:00 AM to 6:00 PM</option>
                                      <option>G2- General =9:30 AM to 6:30 PM</option>
                                      <option>G3- General =9:30 AM to 6:00 PM</option>
                                      <option>G4- Late General =10:00 AM to 7:00 PM</option>
                                      <option>G4- Late General =10:00 AM to 6:30 PM</option>
                                      <option>G5- General =11:00 AM to 7:00:00 PM</option>
                                      <option>G6 - Late General =11:00 AM to 8:00 PM</option>
                                      <option>A-=12:00 PM to  9:00 PM</option>
                                    </select> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Org Name:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10"> <select class="form-control" id="orgName">
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
      </select> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitForm(this)">Check-In</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="submitForm(this)">Check-Out</button> </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
                <div class="well">
                    <p>Login Information</p>
                    <div id="browser"></div>
                    <div id="os"></div>
                    <script src="https://rawgit.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js/master/dist/ua-parser.min.js"></script>
                    <script>
                        var parser = new UAParser();
                        parser.setUA("<?= HtmlService.getUserAgent(); ?>");
                        var result = parser.getResult();
                        document.getElementById("browser").textContent = result.browser.name + " v" + result.browser.major;
                        document.getElementById("os").textContent = result.os.name + " v" + result.os.version;
                    </script>

                    <head>
                        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
                        <script src="https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip"></script>
                        <script>
                            $(function() {
                                $("#ip").html(userip);
                            });
                        </script>
                    </head>

                    <body>
                        <p id="ip"></p>
                    </body> <a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
        </a> </div>
                <div class="well">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);

                        function success(position) {
                            console.log(position.coords.latitude)
                            console.log(position.coords.longitude)
                            var GEOCODING = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + position.coords.latitude + '%2C' + position.coords.longitude + '&language=en';
                            $.getJSON(GEOCODING).done(function(location) {
                                console.log(location)
                            })
                        }

                        function error(err) {
                            console.log(err)
                        }
                    </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>

                    <body>
                        <p>City: <span id="state"></span></p>
                        <p>Address: <span id="address"></span></p>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);

                            function success(position) {
                                var GEOCODING = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + position.coords.latitude + '%2C' + position.coords.longitude + '&language=en';
                                $.getJSON(GEOCODING).done(function(location) {
                                    // $('#country').html(location.results[0].address_components[5].long_name);
                                    $('#state').html(location.results[0].address_components[4].long_name);
                                    // $('#city').html(location.results[0].address_components[2].long_name);
                                    $('#address').html(location.results[0].formatted_address);
                                    // $('#latitude').html(position.coords.latitude);
                                    // $('#longitude').html(position.coords.longitude);
                                })
                            }

                            function error(err) {
                                console.log(err)
                            }
                        </script> <a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
        </a> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
        <p>Test</p>
    </footer>
    </body>
    <script>
        function submitForm(btnClicked) {
            $("button").attr("disabled", true);
            var jsonObj = {};
            jsonObj["IP Address"] = $("#ip").html();
            jsonObj["OS"] = $("#os").html();
            jsonObj["Location"] = $("#state").html() + " | " + $("#address").html();
            jsonObj["Emp Code"] = $("#EmpCode").val();
            jsonObj["Shift Timing"] = $("#shiftTiming").val();
            jsonObj["Org"] = $("#orgName").val();
            jsonObj["Submit"] = $(btnClicked).text();
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterSaving).saveDate(jsonObj);
        }

        function afterSaving() {
            alert("Done!");
            $("button").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    </script>

</html>
```

**Code.gs**

```
function getCurrentUserEmail()
{
  var email={'email':Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()};//returned as an object
  return email;
}

function saveDate(data) {
    var openSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1JTzw2lD2Y_UxzcEMDjoqNYOwnbaqPV8wnkJlK20IqSc").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var sheetHeader = openSpreadSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, openSpreadSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    Logger.log(sheetHeader);
    var arrayToSave = [];
    data["Timestamp"] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, "GMT +1", "YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    data["Email Address"] = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail().toString();
    for (i = 0; i < sheetHeader.length; i++) {
        if (Object.keys(data).indexOf(sheetHeader[i]) != -1) {
            arrayToSave[i] = data[sheetHeader[i]];
        } else {
            arrayToSave[i] = "";
        }
    }       
    openSpreadSheet.appendRow(arrayToSave);
}
```

There are many HTML tag error, make sure you rectify that too.

Comment: Thank you very much .............
How to get Time Stamp - Submit (Check-in /Check-out)
Which button user clicked (Check-in or Check-out)

Comment: The below line of code will record which button user has clicked
`jsonObj["Submit"] = $(btnClicked).text();` // **Make sure the column name in spreadsheet is 'Submit' or change the above object property name to match with the column name**